# How can I display links which emit new code?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In a Jupyter Notebook, I can display links:

```py
from IPython.display import display

class Person:

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return 'Current location: <a href="london">London</a>'

p = Person()
display(p)

# outputs: Current location: London
```

Is it possible to create a link which when clicked, generates a new cell with custom code? In my code example, if someone clicks on "London", I would like to create and run a new cell containing code like

```py
l = get_information("London")
display(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did more research and figured out this is possible using Javascript:

```py
from IPython.display import display

class Person:

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return """
Current location: <a href="#" onclick="
    var code = IPython.notebook.insert_cell_at_bottom('code')
    code.set_text('x=&quot;Some informantion about London&quot;; display(x)')
    code.execute()
">London</a>"""

p = Person()
display(p)
```